# html putting divs on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am working on an html site that has a menu on the side, when I press a menu button I want a hidden div popup on the side of the menu however, when it does that it moves everything down.

Here is some code:

```
<div style="display:none; padding-left:670px; padding-right:5px; float:left" id="second">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <font color="#33FF66"><h2 style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showabout()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></font>

    <font color="#33FF66"><h2 style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showabout()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></font><br />

    <font color="#33FF66"><h2 style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showabout()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h2></font>

</div>

function showabout(){
    show = document.getElementById("aboutus");
    show.style.display = "block";
    }

<div style="display:none; padding-left:20px; float:left" id="aboutus">
    <h2>Hey</h2>
</div>
```

So when I press any of the three `h2` tags it does the `showabout()`. which shows the hidden hello tag, however this moves everything any idea on how to not make it move anything ?

Comment: By looking at code sample you might want to look at something like http://htmldog.com/

You shouldn't be using font tags... ever.

Answer (score 3):

`div` is a [block level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) by definition. You need to set it to `display: inline;` if you don't want a line break after it. (`show.style.display = "inline";`)

Answer (score 0):

1. remove those font tags.

2.

```
<div style="display:none; padding-left:20px; position:absolute; top: 100px; left:100px;" id="aboutus">
<h2>Hey</h2></div>
```

You will have to play with the pixel values but that will allow for a popup effect on that div. I recommend doing some positioning tutorials to get your head around how it works.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/